# Bluescreen errors because of RAM

Tags: windows-10, memory, bsod

Since Windows is taking alot RAM while idle and I like to use my PC for Gaming, but also would like to do some virtualization I thought of upgrading to 32GB RAM instead of 16GB RAM. So I bought the G.Skill Ripjaws V F4-3600C18D-32GVK with 3600 MHz.

The problem: Sometimes, when I use my PC, it just gets me into a BSOD. The weird thing is that I always get different Error Codes.

These are just some of the BSODs that I got (unfortunately I have not documented every error code):

- **MEMORY_MANAGEMENT**
- **KERNEL_DATA_INPAGE_ERROR**
- **ATTEMPTED_WRITE_TO_READONLY_MEMORY**
- **PAGE_FAULT_IN_NONPAGED_AREA**
- **SYSTEM_SERVICE_EXCEPTION**

Then I switched my RAM with my old RAM (KINGSTON KHX3000C15D4) and everything just worked. Tested it for 3 full days and had no single BSOD.

So I figured it was probably the RAM, so I installed memtest86 on one of my USB sticks. The tests with the new RAM have failed while these with my old RAM have succeeded. I'm now not sure whether my RAM is faulty, if I misconfigured something in the BIOS or the RAM is just not compatible with my motherboard/CPU. The latter option would confuse me tho, since the old RAM, that I am using currently and is working perfectly fine, is officialy unsupported too, or at least not listed in the supported memory list of my motherboard/CPU.

I also put the new RAM in the exact same RAM slots as the old ones.

- Motherboard: GIGABYTE B450 GAMING X
- CPU: AMD Ryzen 7 3700X 8-Core Processor
- New RAM: 2x G.Skill Ripjaws V F4-3600C18D-32GVK 3600MHz 16GB
- Old RAM: 2x KINGSTON KHX3000C15D4 3000MHz 8 GB

Comment: _"Windows is taking alot RAM while idle"_ - citation needed. It could be that the new RAM is DOA. Make sure your BIOS is up to date though, they could have improved compatibility.

Comment: If memory fails memtest it's sure thing. You can try different test but reason seems obvious - faulty chips. You better take a picture of the failed test and prepare to return to the seller.

Comment: > Make sure your BIOS is up to date though; @gronostaj: it only made sens if his BIOS didn't support 32GiB. If it does it has nothing to do with "compatibility".

Comment: @tansy Actually it's not unheard of for BIOS updates to improve memory compatibility for modules that theoretically should be fine, but in practice don't work. Usually these don't work at all though until the update is installed, but it won't hurt to check.

Comment: I updated my BIOS 4 months ago to F61. The 2 newer versions (F62 and F63a) don't seem to have any new compatibility features.

Comment: That would it about compatibility.
That leaves hardware fault. If you have someone with the computer that can test this RAM on it it would be decisive.

Comment: Run Memtest86 with **only** the new stick fitted. If you get errors then return it and get a replacement.

Comment: > _"Windows is taking alot RAM while idle"_
It does. I have a browser (1200MB), file manager (80MB), Tor (50MB), torrent (24MB), python (9MB), net meter (30MB), procexplorer (50MB) = 1443MB. And system commit is 7.8 GB.

Comment: @Mokubai do you mean to use only the new RAM sticks? If yes, I already did test this. This was when the error came.

Comment: Then send it back as it is faulty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you checked all compatibility, you could have a bad stick of RAM. I would try putting in 1 stick at a time and see if it holds up. I have had a similar issue, can could not figure out why it wouldn't work, and turned out to be just a bad stick of RAM. Returned the bad one for a replacement and that did the trick.